# How can I shift the Matlab legend from one plot to another subplot while maintaining the plot's original size?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

My chart has a total of 12 data lines, with dashed lines representing the right axis (R) and solid lines representing the left axis (L).
My chart, sans the legend:[the figure before the legend is added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydvo6.png)
after the chart's legend is added:[Figure after the addition of captions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEelZ.png)

How can I shift the Matlab legend from one plot to another subplot while maintaining the plot's original size? Or, please share your thoughts with me if you have any.
Some of the pictures I may desire are these:
[above the chart, a figure with a legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNIrr.png)
[the figure below the chart with a legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjsP4.png)
...
This might be a sample that is comparable to mine:

```
%% create 12 random data, 6 for the left and 6 for the right y-axes.
x = linspace(1,5,100);
datY_Left ={normrnd(2,2,size(x)),normrnd(5.5,3,size(x)),normrnd(4,4.5,size(x)),normrnd(3.5,3,size(x)),normrnd(2,2,size(x)),normrnd(3.2,1.8,size(x))};
nameYL = {'Data1,YLeft','Data2,YLeft','Data3,YLeft','Data4,YLeft','Data5,YLeft','Data5,YLeft'};
colorYL = {'c','m','r','k','b','g'}; 
datY_Right = {normrnd(1.5,2,size(x)),normrnd(3,3,size(x)),normrnd(2,4.5,size(x)),normrnd(3,3,size(x)),normrnd(2.5,2,size(x)),normrnd(3,1.5,size(x))};
nameYR = {'Data1,YRight','Data2,YRight','Data3,YRight','Data4,YRight','Data5,YRight','Data5,YRight'};
colorYR = {'c','m','r','k','b','g'};
%% draw a graph with the recently generated data.
figure;
    yyaxis left
        for m = 1:length(datY_Left)
            plot(x,datY_Left{m},'-','Color',colorYL{m},'DisplayName',nameYL{m});
            hold on;
            set(gca,'YLim',[-5 10]);
        end
    yyaxis right
        for m = 1:length(datY_Right)
            plot(x,datY_Right{m},'--','Color',colorYR{m},'DisplayName',nameYR{m});
            hold on;
            set(gca,'YLim',[-10 10]);
        end
    lgd = legend('-DynamicLegend', 'Location', 'northoutside');
    set(lgd, 'NumColumns', 2)
```

Comment: Did you read the docuementation to `legend`? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html#bt6ef_q-1-lcn

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "maintaining its original size"? Is the size changing somehow?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I went to create subplots for legend and modified the legend places in Matlab, but it appears that my legend is taking up the entire data graph.

Comment: @AnderBiguri "maintain its original size" means that when I create a chart without a legend, I design it with height (H) and width (W), and then I add my chart legend, which also I want to preserve the height (H) and width (W) of the charts as, at maximum, the caption will fill the full chart (the chart still has the same dimensions). When I make a subplot to write a legend, my data remains unchanged, and moving the legend will not alter the size of the chart.

Comment: I still don't know what you are saying sorry. Can you show code of that produces a figure that you don't like, and code with Cris suggestion, and tell us why it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, exactly, this is it. This is the code that plots my comparable data.

Comment: I don’t understand. You don’t want the legend to be on top of your plot, and you don’t want to leave space in your figure outside your plot for the legend when you are designing the plot. You will have to do one of the two, because you can’t put the legend outside the figure.